# How to protect my Python scripts on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I have developed a long and complex computer vision algorithm on Python. I insist on the "long and complex" because my very last solution would be to rewrite it with C++ (it's about 3 000 lines long and depends on pure Python libraries)...

This algorithm is embedded on a Raspberry Pi A+. It is possible to plug an SD card to this nanocomputer, so that it includes a Linux system.

So basically my script is in a folder in that SD. When the Raspberry Pi is switched on, it runs the system and then executes my code.

Let's say someone retrieve this SD card. How can I be sure that he won't be able to get to my script ?

I've read it was difficult to obfuscate Python code, is it still true ? Let's say I would rename all of my variables with absurd names, to "scramble the tracks". Are there programs that can retrace the structure of the whole algorithm ?

Regarding the SD card itself, is it possible to protect it ? 
What I am actually doing is I deactivate the HDMI and USB port when the Raspberry Pi is launched, and protect the SSH connexion with a password. 
Do you think this is enough, or is there other ways someone can get to the script ?

Finally, rewritting it in C++... Would it ensure me that it would be 100% protected ?!

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: compile into a .pyc file

Comment: @Kev1n91 That won't help much.

Comment: Yes I tried it : my files are only hexadecimal code. The problem is : I was able to get back to the .py file with an open-source library called uncompyle2 (even the comments!) :(

Comment: Why not just encrypt the home directory which the script stores?

Answer (score 2):

I think your best solution would be to compile your Python file using a  bundling tool.

See [Compiling Python Code](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm).

For example using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

Although you can never (even with C++) guarantee full "protection". There are techniques like [reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) that can be used to reveal your algorithm.